Java, Android Studio & Gradle: Confused about Compatibility Matrix
I am running the latest version of Android Studio (Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2) and Java 21 (I was running Java 23 before while trying to get it to work with Gradle 8.10 but have not had success so I downgraded to Java 21 because of it's LTS but without understanding why my app did not run on Java 23/Gradle 8.10 which should be perfect match according to the compatibility metrics).
According to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html Java is compatible with Gradle 8.5 and Supports toolchain 8.4 (I unfortunately do not know the difference between toolchain and gradle).
When I try to sync my project, it tells me Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 8.4. Cannot sync the project. which I do not understand.
In search for help I found multiple question, this one seems to show most of the things I do not understand though: Can't resolve "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1" error when building Flutter Android app in VSCode Here, Ali Al-Amrad recommends to use a lower gradle version, probably because Gradle 8.2.1 is not compatible with Java/JVM 19.
Kairat says Gradle 8.2 requires Java 11 or higher while the metrics says Java 11 can only run Gradle up to 5.0 (so Gradle versions higher then 5.0 need a higher Java version, right?)
Some users even recommended downgrading Android Studio.
By now, I am totally confused about the Java versions, the compatibility metrics (which looks really straight forward but seems to be missunderstood by me) and hope someone can help me to better understand it!
My code recommends me to upgrade to Gradle 8.9 which would mean to move back to Java 23.

"Java is compatible with Gradle 8.5" I think you left out the Java version... In any case, your error suggests you're trying to use Gradle 8.4(!) not Gradle 8.5, with Java 21 and that is not compatible; what does work is using a toolchain configuration for Java 21, while running Gradle 8.4 itself on an older Java version.

And the linked page does not say that Java 11 only works with Gradle 5; it just means that Gradle 5 was the first version to support Java 11.

Perhaps you meant matrices rather than metrics.

I'm in the same situation.  Question should not be closed.
